# Delphi Android consuming Android API - Handpoint

Tags: android, api, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I need some help with accessing `JObject` methods.

This is the API Interface converted with Java2OP:

```
JTransactionType = interface;//com.handpoint.api.TransactionType

JTransactionResultClass = interface(JObjectClass)
['{A5821CF6-DC08-4DDA-BD34-DCF5E8BCA6CC}']
{class} function getCustomerReceipt: JString; cdecl;//Deprecated
end;

[JavaSignature('com/handpoint/api/TransactionResult')]
JTransactionResult = interface(JObject)
['{3BFB1C2D-0B3E-4C5D-9A8D-7A92C3F4F45E}']
end;
TJTransactionResult = class(TJavaGenericImport<JTransactionResultClass, JTransactionResult>) end;
```

The following method triggers as a response from the API:

```
procedure TApiResponse.endOfTransaction(P1: JTransactionResult; P2: JDevice);
begin
  fMessage := JStringToString(TJTransactionResult.JavaClass.getCustomerReceipt);
end;
```

I am looking to call `P1.getCustomerReceipt()`, but I am not sure how to cast or access the class method.

Comment: The code outputted by Java2Op is wrong. `CustomerReceipt` is not a `static` property of the `TransactionResult` class, so it does not belong in `JTransactionResultClass`, it belongs in `JTransactionResult` instead

Comment: Spot on. Thank you. I now only have segmentation fault left... but will add in another question

Comment: Not sure if this is allowed - but here is link to other question related to API implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52918973/delphi-android-api-implementation-segmentation-vault-handpoint

Comment: As per Remy suggestion - this solved by problem and I am now able to get result

 `JTransactionResultClass = interface(JObjectClass)
 ['{A5821CF6-DC08-4DDA-BD34-DCF5E8BCA6CC}']
 end;

 [JavaSignature('com/handpoint/api/TransactionResult')]
 JTransactionResult = interface(JObject)
 ['{3BFB1C2D-0B3E-4C5D-9A8D-7A92C3F4F45E}']
 {class} function getCustomerReceipt: JString; cdecl;//Deprecated
 end;`

Comment: `CustomerReceipt` is not a `class` (aka `static`) method, so remove the `{class}` comment. Also, it is technically a property, so you *should* add a property for consistency: `[JavaSignature('com/handpoint/api/TransactionResult')] JTransactionResult = interface(JObject) ['{3BFB1C2D-0B3E-4C5D-9A8D-7A92C3F4F45E}'] function getCustomerReceipt: JString; cdecl; property CustomerReceipt: JString read getCustomerReceipt; end;` And then, you should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) to let Embarcadero know that Java2Op is outputting bad code for this API.

Comment: Bug report logged: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21462

Comment: @Happy I have added a comment to the report